# Connecting Access Table to ArcGIS (Replace Function!)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table, ms-access

I have an Access Query where the Field names contain symbols like "-", ":" and spaces. When I was connecting my database to ArcCatalogue that specific Query-table was not visible. Then I used Replace function (in Access) to replace those symbols and spaces to "_". Then the table was visible in ArcMap. I did lots of mapping with that and suddenly after few weeks that Table is no longer connecting. My all ArcMap data links are broken. I read somewhere that the Replace function does not work out of Access environment. Then how was it working 2 months ago and now its not connecting? Is anyone experiencing similar problem? any suggestion?